# Convert from Oracle to SQL Server script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can somebody help me to convert the code shown below to SQL Server?

```sql
SELECT yyy 
INTO xxx 
FROM ccc 
WHERE zzz = 'aaa';
```

I tried like this and it works too:

```sql
SELECT @xxx = yyy 
FROM ccc 
WHERE zzz= 'aaa';
```

But is there any other way to pass the value returned by select to a parameter?

Comment: What does not fit the second example `SELECT @xxx = yyy FROM ccc WHERE zzz= 'aaa';`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be , supposing the var1 variable which matches the column in your table is an integer, if not replace it with the right data type.

```
declare @var1 int;
select 
    @var1 = field1
from
    ccc
where
    zzz = 'aaa' ;
```

Comment: Thank you Roberto, I already tried this and is working.. just wanted to be sure and know if there are any other ways. Appreciate !

Comment: I think the way you are using it is ok.